# I have a question ban and I have no idea how to fix it

Tags: support, user-accounts, asking-questions, post-ban

I'm unable to post questions, but stack exchange does not point out what is wrong with my posts, nor give me good direction beyond "edit your questions". So it expects me to blindly edit my questions with the hope I'll fix them? Seriously? If I knew the questions were lacking when I posted them, I wouldn't have posted them like that!

As far as I can tell they are fine. Every time someone says I didn't give enough info I fix it. I have a few down voted questions, and I fix those questions the best I can, but I can't force people to upvote them afterwards. Am I just screwed?

What are my options? This is entirely unfair and frustrating beyond belief!

Comment: You wait 6 months then submit a high quality question. The only other way to improve your existing questions. Deleting your existing questions will not lift the question ban, in fact deleting questions that are not well received, will only make it harder to raise you above the threshold that makes a question ban necessary. Question bans are always due to a continued pattern of asking questions that are not well received.

Comment: In conclusion the only real solution is to ask better questions. There isn’t a way for anyone to lift the question ban. Only your positive contributions can do that. Creating a new account will only get the new account immediately delete and the original account suspended for bypassing a question ban.

Comment: Yes, I think my question has been answered, I'm screwed. SE needs to reconsider their policy. I have no idea how to improve my questions, and SE gives no direction on what to do other than a vague and unhelpful "make them better". My questions were fine from the beginning, or I improved after clarification was requested. No one is going to score them higher so without the opportunity to ask new "good" questions I have no means to get out of this situation. Thanks SE!

Comment: Your not “screwed”, many users start submitting high quality questions and are essentially end up above the threshold that makes the question ban necessary

Answer (score 8):

### I don’t know why you have a ban, but your vandalism of your own questions doesn’t help.

You went to all your questions (spanning from 2017 to 2023) and edited them to complain about your ban? How do you think that would help you? In pretty much all of your edits state the following:

> “I'm editing this question because I have a question ban. SE says my questions aren't good enough (I think they are), and they do not give adequate reasoning for this, and give no directions on what do change. Good job SE!”

I reverted them all but come on… Throwing tantrums won’t help you.

Here are the posts in question with my own notes:

- [How to prevent users from altering the BIOS?](https://superuser.com/revisions/1799886/2): From Jul 25, 2023. Has an answer but also an extensive amount of comments. I don’t see what the problem is. You might not like the answer, but I think all is fine with the question and the answer as well as the comments.
- [Can use these 3 8-pin connectors for my 3090?](https://superuser.com/revisions/1681986/3): From Oct 16, 2021. Again, that question has an answer and I don’t see what the problem is.
- [Cannot assign drive letter to SD card partition](https://superuser.com/revisions/1458937/3): From Jul 12, 2019. You discovered an answer on your own and ask, “How would I make it the first one?” So effectively your question is one thing in the main question and another in the “UPDATE.” Your question needs to be clear.
- [Wireless USB extension](https://superuser.com/revisions/1402086/2): From Feb 5, 2019. You provided no details on the printer. Your question is so vague as to be broad. Come on.
- [CPU or GPU for x264 encoding](https://superuser.com/revisions/1177892/2): From Feb 11, 2017. This is not a question that is a good for for Stack Exchange sites since are asking the community for an opinion as well as shopping advice.

And you state this:

> “Every time someone says I didn't give enough info I fix it.”

Nope! Three of the five questions here show no such edits on your part. The questions are still vague and votes to close based on lack of detail are still in play.

Why do you have a question ban? I don’t know how the Stack Exchange algorithm works. But I cannot imagine you editing your own questions, which span **6 years**, to complain helps.

Looking at your question asking record show a total of five questions. Two of the five are good… The remaining three are bad in various, obvious ways.

How can you get past the ban? I don’t know. But I think positively contributing via answers and edits can help.